# Pointer to pointer confusion

Tags: c, pointers

Edit: The reason queue is 2d is because I need a pointer of Command so that cmd can equal NULL. NULL == (void *). This is where I get confused though, and why I've come here. :)

To help try and figure out another problem I have in Python, I'm implementing a small test program in C. While I know a little, apparently I'm confused. I'm trying to write a simple queue to be used in asynchronous USB transfers. Something's not right with queue, as every command popped from the queue is the same. If I write queue[1024][0] as queue[1024][1] instead, the command alternates between two distinct commands, and the program crashes in command_thread_main. Apparently it doesn't notice that cmd should be NULL. Changing [1] any higher has no effect as far as I can tell. Any hints?

```
typedef struct Command {
    void (*cb) (char *data, int size);
    unsigned char *data;
    int size;
} Command;

struct Command queue[1024][0];

int queueEnd = 0;
int queueStart = 0;

static void queue_push(void (*cb), unsigned char *data, int size) {
    if (queueEnd >= 1024)
        return;
    queue[queueEnd]->cb = cb;
    queue[queueEnd]->data = data;
    queue[queueEnd]->size = size;
    queueEnd++;
}

struct Command * queue_pop(void) {
    if( queueStart > queueEnd )
        return NULL;
    return queue[queueStart++];
}

static void *command_thread_main(void *arg) {
    struct Command *cmd;
    while (!do_exit) {
        if(locked) continue;
        locked = 1;
        cmd = queue_pop();
        if(cmd != NULL)
            cmd->cb(cmd->data, cmd->size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the array 2D? that looks wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't you mean `struct Command queue[1024];`? (That is, no `[0]` or `[1]` or whatever.)
- In `queue_pop` I think you should test for `queueStart >= queueEnd`.
- <strike>You should implement a circular array.</strike>

Right now you store the struct itself in an array, not pointers to it. That is sensible. You'll need to change `->` to `.` though:

```
queue[queueEnd].cb = cb;
queue[queueEnd].data = data;
queue[queueEnd].size = size;
```

(And hence `queue_pop` should return a variable of type `struct Command` (not `struct Command *`), and the main code should also be updated accordingly.)

Of course you *can* also pass pointers around, but with such a small struct/queue there's no actual need.

Comment: 1) I need a pointer. 2) Once queueStart passes queueEnd, the queue's considered empty. When queueStart == queueEnd, queue has at least one member to pop. 3) This queue's going to be used once, with 65 commands at most passed through it. It's a simple test program to satisfy someone who's helping me debug an issue in Python. No circular array needed!

Comment: Initially `queueStart = queueEnd = 0`, so then `queueStart > queueEnd` is false, while the queue is in fact empty. Your code will never pop the last command.

Comment: Makes a little more sense. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm saying it the wrong way around: your code pops one value to many (which will result in undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a bug you need to fix before anything else. You have a 2D array of commands and have set one of those dimensions to zero!

```
struct Command queue[1024][0];
```

When you access queue you seem to treat it as a 1D structure. Should you declare it as :

```
struct Command queue[1024];
```

Comment: Either have queue_pop return `&queue[queueStart++]` or change the array to be Command *

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, that 2D queue is definitely wrong. You need a 1D queue, and I suspect that what you want is an array of pointers:

```
Command * queue[1024];
```

I reommend you go a way and think about the problem a bit, draw some diagrams and then come back with clearer code and question.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is that you've declared queue as an array of `struct`s, but you're using it as an array of pointers to structs by using the dereferencing `->` operator instead of the membership `.` one.

I don't mean to sound snarky, but compiler warning flags (`-Wall` for gcc) are your friends.

Comment: 1) This is why I'm here. It's apparent I'm doing something wrong, but I wasn't sure what that might be. How would you suggest I do this differently? 2) Ah, yeah I'm new to C and compiling C. Thanks for the compiler tip.

Comment: Since it's a simple program, the queue is a global variable, and no space in the queue is ever reused I'd just let pop return an index to the popped value, or -1 if the queue is empty.

Also, you should use proper mutexes, really.

Comment: Well, there's absolutely no need for mutexes. The queue's filled before the threads are started. Like I said, it's a very simply program. I just needed a queue to hold about 65 USB transfers for command_thread_main to consume.

Comment: My mistake; I was confused by the use of a 'locked' variable in your example.

Comment: Ah yes :) That state changes with each USB transfer (true) and it's corresponding callback (false).